# Execute a script when accessing an image by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible if you access an image on a server that it can execute a script separately by using .htaccess, for example (pseudo code):

```
-> user views http://www.mywebsite.com/images/systems_analysis.jpg;
    -> .htaccess gets the image name (systems_analysis.jpg);
    -> then executes viewed.php?img=systems_analysis.jpg;
-> leaving viewed.php to process with the script.
```

So when an image is being viewed, it will execute the `viewed.php` script that will only be executed when images are accessed in the `/images/` directory.

Comment: Set up a mod_rewrite rule to change hits on `/images/whatever` into `viewed.php?img=whatever`

Comment: @Marc but that means viewed.php needs to pass through the requested resource, which is sub-optimal... Can't think of a better way though

Comment: You could send an HTTP Redirect in the php script, so you don't need to pass the resource through the script. But it is not the best way i can imagine either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /viewed.php?image=$1
```

The above .htaccess entry will rewrite the following request:

yourdomain.com/some_image.jpg -> youdomain.com/viewed.php?image=some_image

Comment: I don't need any rewrites, I need a script to be executed in the background when an image has been accessed.

Comment: @lolwut: I don't think Apache can split requests like that. You might have to have your script do both whatever it is it has to, as well as actually serve up the image.

Comment: this code gave me an Internal Server Error or I didn't done it right?

Comment: @jun you will actually have to handle the request in your PHP script successfully.

Comment: I push this up as I am looking for a solution like that too.